# Parametrized left-right operator

Tags: macros

We are used to `\left` and `\right` operators, each followed by delimiters, among others, `\{\}[]().\lvert\rvert`. My question is: is it possible to generate a shortcut command `\lr` such that `\lr{\{, \}, \frac{a}{b}}` gives the same output as `\left\{ \frac{a}{b} \right\}` ?

Best regards,

Bruno Peixoto

Comment: Not the syntax you suggest but see `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools` (which will also correct the horizontal space issues from`\left\right`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what this would be useful for…

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lr}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}m}{%
  \dolr#1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\dolr}{mmm}{%
  \left#1 #3 \right#2%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\lr{\{,\},\frac{a}{b}}
+
\lr{(,),\frac{a}{b}}
+
\lr{[,],\frac{a}{b}}
\]

\end{document}
```

With `\SplitArgument{2}{,}` the given argument is passed to the internal macro as three braced groups, so we can define `\dolr` with three arguments as needed.

[image]

Perhaps more interesting would be a much more flexible key-value interface. The size can be manually specified via `big` or similar; for automatic sizing. use `*`. The shape of the delimiters is specified with a syntax similar to how `amsmath` does for matrices:

- `p` for parentheses
- `b` for brackets
- `B` for braces
- `v` for single bars
- `V` for double bars
- `a` for angle brackets

If you have nonstandard delimiters you can always do `left=<del>` and `right=<del>`.

Inside the mandatory argument of `\lr` you can use `|` which will produce a vertical bar that extends like the outer fences.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\lr}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { peixoto/lr } { size, left=., right=.,  #1 }
  \char_set_active_eq:nN { `| } \__peixote_lr_del:
  \char_set_mathcode:nn { `| } { "8000 }
  \peixoto_lr:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { peixoto/lr }
 {
  left .tl_set:N = \l__peixoto_lr_leftdel_tl,
  right .tl_set:N = \l__peixoto_lr_rightdel_tl,
  lp .meta:n = { left=( },
  rp .meta:n = { right=) },
  p .meta:n = { lp,rp },
  lb .meta:n = { left=[ },
  rb .meta:n = { right=] },
  b .meta:n = { lb,rb },
  lB .meta:n = { left=\{ },
  rB .meta:n = { right=\} },
  B .meta:n = { lB,rB },
  lv .meta:n = { left=\lvert },
  rv .meta:n = { right=\rvert },
  v .meta:n = { lv,rv },
  lV .meta:n = { left=\lVert },
  rV .meta:n = { right=\rVert },
  V .meta:n = { lV,rV },
  la .meta:n = { left=\langle },
  ra .meta:n = { right=\rangle },
  a .meta:n = { la,ra },
  size .code:n =
    \tl_set:Nx \l__peixoto_leftsize_tl  { \exp_not:c { __peixoto_lr_#1l: } }
    \tl_set:Nx \l__peixoto_midsize_tl   { \exp_not:c { __peixoto_lr_#1m: } }
    \tl_set:Nx \l__peixoto_rightsize_tl { \exp_not:c { __peixoto_lr_#1r: } },
  size .default:n = {},
  big .meta:n = { size = big },
  Big .meta:n = { size = Big },
  bigg .meta:n = { size = bigg },
  Bigg .meta:n = { size = Bigg },
  * .code:n =
    \tl_set:Nn \l__peixoto_leftsize_tl { \mleft }
    \tl_set:Nn \l__peixoto_midsize_tl { \;\middle\vert\; }
    \tl_set:Nn \l__peixoto_rightsize_tl { \mright },
}
\tl_new:N \l__peixoto_leftsize_tl
\tl_new:N \l__peixoto_rightsize_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \peixoto_lr:n
 {
  \l__peixoto_leftsize_tl\l__peixoto_lr_leftdel_tl
  #1
  \l__peixoto_rightsize_tl\l__peixoto_lr_rightdel_tl
}

\cs_new:Nn \__peixoto_lr_l: {}
\cs_new:Nn \__peixoto_lr_m: {\mid}
\cs_new:Nn \__peixoto_lr_r: {}
\clist_map_inline:nn { big,Big,bigg,Bigg }
 {
  \cs_new_eq:cc {__peixoto_lr_#1l:} {#1l}
  \cs_new_protected:cn {__peixoto_lr_#1m:} {\use:c{#1m}\vert}
  \cs_new_eq:cc {__peixoto_lr_#1r:} {#1r}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__peixote_lr_del: { \tl_use:N \l__peixoto_midsize_tl }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% example shorthands
\NewDocumentCommand{\lrp}{O{}m}{\lr[p,#1]{#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\bra}{O{}m}{\lr[la,rv,#1]{#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ket}{O{}m}{\lr[lv,ra,#1]{#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\braket}{O{}m}{\lr[a,#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\[
\lr[B,*]{\frac{a}{b}}
+
\lr[p,Big]{\frac{a}{b}}
+
\lr[b,bigg]{\frac{a}{b}}
+
\lr[v,*]{\frac{a}{b}}
+
\lr[V,*]{\frac{a}{b}}
+
\lr[a,*]{\frac{a}{b}}
+
\lr[la,rv,Big]{\frac{a}{b}}
\]

\[
\lr[p]{a+b}^2
\quad
\lr[b,big]{a\lr[p]{b+c}^2-1}^3
\]

\[
\ket{x}\bra{y}+\lrp[big]{a+b}+\braket{a | b}
\]

\[
\ket[big]{x}\bra[Big]{y}+\braket[bigg]{a | b}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a mathematician solves a problem that an engineer asks "What for?" first.

Comment: Bravo, bravíssimo!

Comment: Suggestion: I see entry possibilities:

1. `\lr[group_string]{content}`;
2; `\lr[group_string, size_string]{content}`;
3. `\lr[left_group_string, right_group_string]{content}`;
4. `\lr[left_group_string, right_group_string, size]{content}`;

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto Yes, that's the idea. You can specify left and right separately with `lx` and `ry`, or together with a single letter. Maybe you use `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket`, so you can specify `\lr[left=\llbracket,right=\rrbracket]{formula}`. It's possible to add new shorthands, just follow the pattern.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto I added a couple of examples of how you can use it in the real world.

Comment: I see you added bra-ckets example. I like the former.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto Other important changes made. Please, update.

Comment: May you express in words your main modifications?

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto There were a few weaknesses that needed a fix but don’t affect the user level. I also added a user level feature, namely that `|` in the formula argument to `\lr` Produces an extensible vertical bar, as shown with `\braket`.

Comment: You should substiute `peixote_lr` by `bruno_enrico_lr`. :-) . My name is Bruno Henrique, btw. ;-P

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto Or `bigfish`, if we want to use English. 

Comment: I think `richfish` or `rish` are good choices.

Comment: I come once again to extend this answer. The `only-left` and `only-right` are righteous left aside. :-/ I have some idea how to do it, but I leave to the creator to tame the creature.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto `left=\{,\right=.`

Comment: Yeah, but in `rish`-standards.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto `\lr[left=\{,right=.]{a}` will work, where's the problem?

Comment: I was the main problem. You solved it like a charm.

Comment: Challenge of the day: Allow command to define inner delimiter between elements. Example: `\lr[big,p]{a}{b}{c}{x}{y}{z}`. Output: (a,b,c,x,y,z)

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto Sorry, but this is against every syntax convention. And typing in `\lr[big,p]{a,b,c,d,e,f}` is *much* simpler.

Comment: Bruno is sad. :-(

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto You shouldn't be. I might think to something like `\lr[big,p,list=;]{a,b,c,d,e,f}` with output (a;b;c;d;e;f) (with customizable symbol between the items). That's by no means difficult. Using a variable number of arguments is not something I'd pursue (there are several related questions on the site). Anyway, processing the delimiters and the argument are different things and overloading a command with too many options becomes difficult to maintain and to *remember*.

Comment: btw, find the error `b .meta:n = { lp,rp },`.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto I'll fix, thanks.

Comment: Thanks are there to share.

Comment: One more challenge: self-adjustable left-right delimiters size.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto see `*`

Comment: I see you keep your pencils sharpen and your pen cartridges half-full.

Comment: It means `\NewDocumentCommand{\lrs}{O{}m}{\lr[#1,*]{#2}}`.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto Among the keys there’s `*` that means autosize: it’s the very first example. You can define `\lrs`, if you want, but I’d not recommend it.

Comment: :'-( Tell me why? Backstreet Boys asked for it.

Comment: The answer to the following question seems a task to super-@egreg:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670819/suppress-double-page-behavior-to-insert-library-page-immedistely-after-title-pag

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with native commands declaration

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\lr}[3]{\left#1 #3 \right#2}

\begin{document}
    $\lr{\{} {\}} {\frac{a}{b}}$
\end{document}
```

### Explanation:

the number `3` in `[3]` indicates that 3 arguments are required for this command. Then, every `#` indicates the position of each argument.