# Command `\RequirePackage` and packages conflict

Tags: document-classes

I come from [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670819/suppress-double-page-behavior-to-insert-library-page-immedistely-after-title-pag/670885?noredirect=1#comment1667666_670885) both enlightened and with a question mark over my head:

The command `\makeatletter \makeatother` requires packages, in my case `pdfpages` and `xpatch`. In so far I use these only inside the file `template.tex`, there is no further complication, and the proposed solution rests.

HOWEVER, since my next intention is to integrate it into the class file `politex.cls`, I require to use the command `\RequirePackage[package_name]` to allow me to use its available features.

So far, so good. When I add the rows below on [`politex.cls`](https://github.com/alloyha/TheXis/blob/master/politex.cls), the file `template.tex` stops compiling.

```
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
```

Comment: `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` should not require any packages (of course code that comes in between might, but the two commands are defined in the LaTeX kernel).

Comment: But if you need packages and want to load them in a `.cls` file then `\RequirePackage` as you show is how you'd usually do it. Note that in a `.cls` file you won't need and shouldn't use `\makeatletter...\makeatother`. These commands are only needed in a `.tex` document when you mess with internal commands.

Comment: (Flying) Moewe, may you give some further advice on how to adequate `.tex` code snippet on `.cls` file?

Comment: I don't really understand which snippet you need to implant into your `.cls` file, but usually the rule is that any code can just go into the `.cls` with `\usepackage` replaced with `\RequirePackage` and the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` removed. Your class is very long and complex, though, so it is possible that there are load order classes or code order issues.

Comment: This is the main subject on the issue: investigate the reason for `xpatch` and `pdfpages` raises errors. :-/

Comment: Well what kind of errors do you get? At the moment we have no idea what exactly you are trying to compile, so the exact error messages you get would at least give some hint as to what is wrong.

Comment: Coding is a very introspective activity: I ended up importing the GitHub repo to overleaf in a separate project and was able to `\RequirePackage` both packages. There must be some TexStudio editor issue. I will close this issue and walk around like nothing really happened. Have a nice day!

Comment: If you are going to edit `politex.cls` it is not necessary to patch `\folhaderosto`. Just change the command definition.

Comment: Hi again, @SimonDispa. It is nice to see you here. In my case, I would incorporate the `\usepackage` as `\RequirePackage` and add the snippet after the command definition. It would be very nice to have a command like on `bibtex` which the user sets the path to reference file: in case it is a valid file, it replaces a stub pdf file.